# How could I implement an AWS S3 retry policy on Laravel Storage facade?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, storage

With our software growing, we are sometimes experimenting marginal S3 503 errors. As explained by AWS on https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/http-5xx-errors-s3/ this is normal, and we should implement a retry mechanism such as https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/RetryMiddleware.php.

I think I understand how to do that in the context of custom code, but our code uses Laravel Storage facade (Storage::get(), put(), disk(), append(), delete(), exists()...).

What would be the correct way to implement a retry middleware for a standard facade? Eg stay as close as possible to Laravel standard?

Comment: At an old place of mine we used to use [jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues) for any AWS file tasks.

Basically file gets saved local to machine on user upload. Job dispatched for S3 upload.
Job attempts S3 upload. On failure a back-off strategy is used. On success the local file is cleared.